# pylint error Distribution not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, pylint

I don't understand, why I am getting this error even when I have update pylint.

Although my default python is 2.7 on OSx.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pylint", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pylint==1.0.0
```

i also installed PIP and getting an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.4.1
```

Comment: I have some doubts here , like why is there a mention of the 2.6 version? have you tried this on another machines/pc/laptop?

Comment: i had path set in my .bash_profile to use python 2.7 so i commented that and still i get the same error..

Comment: @san I have also received this error along, but when trying to use pyjamas to compile. do you have any luck on how this is happening? I am thinking of trying to set up python 3.x.x

Comment: I had multiple setups of python but the default one was different verison setup in pip wrapper or in case of pylint, so I went in these wrapper and edited it.